# The C# compiler and memory management

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, malloc

I'm doing a compiler design class on the topic of memory management. I am reading about garbage collection and noticed that most of that low level stuff takes place with C/C++ code. I have a few questions about the c# compiler.

1. Was .net framework part for memory
   management written in c/c++?
2. How does .net manages memory?
3. Does their internal garbage
   collection uses malloc()?
4. What method of garbage collection
   does the .net framework use?

I'd probably use answers to generate new questions but I'm not sure If I should create a new question or edit this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see:

- MSDN Magazine: [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)
- [.NET Framework Developer's Guide: Automatic Memory Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx)
- [.NET Framework Developer's Guide: Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx)
- [Understanding Garbage Collection in .NET](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Much of this type of information can be found in [CLR via C#](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6522&locale=en-us) (or from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632)).  Note that it [sounds like](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2009/06/17/clr-via-c-3rd-edition.aspx) the book will be updated for .NET 4.0.