# Tabcontrol memory leak

Tags: wpf, memory, mvvm, tabcontrol, memory-leaks

im using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

I find that the tab control's tab are not releasing memory upon closing.

Anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Memory doesn't always get released immediately by the CLR.
Because your question is about a sample from MSDN magazine, let me answer you with other articles from the same magazine...

- [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) (by Jeffrey Richter)
- [Garbage Collectionn Part 2: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)
- [CLR Inside Out - Investigating Memory Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx)

These articles are a little older and i could have pointed out newer versions, i just thought it was rather poetic to get your answers from the same place.

For newer articles, try these:

- [Automatic Memory Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f144e03t.aspx)
- [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx)
- [Understanding Garbage Collection in .NET](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/)

(Note that these last three have been stolen shamelessly from [Mitch Wheat's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584012/the-c-compiler-and-memory-management/1584024#1584024).)

Comment: +1 for the Jeffrey Richter article.  All .NET developers should read his CLR Via C#.

Comment: -1 for a generic answer. There are leaks in Prism, etc that need to be worked around.

Comment: @DaveHillier no problems, you are entitled to vote how you want. Do note though that the question was not about Prism, nor is there any mention of Prism whatsoever in the linked article that the OP says he is using. You are probably better off actually adding an answer that gives more details about Prism's memory leaks.